# git command not found in bash script on windows machine

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

I'm trying to write a script for some of basic git operations, in that getting an issue `git status: command not found`

I'm trying it on:
- Windows machine
- bash script
- running script from `git bash`
- git is installed at `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`

Below is the sample script I'm trying with:

```js
path_to_git='/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/'
PATH=$PATH:$path_to_git
echo $PATH
export PATH

res=$("git status")
echo $res
```

Please guide me through, thanks

Comment: Why the double quotes here: `res=$("git status")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting like you did makes the shell look for a command called `git status` instead of `git` with an argument `status` – drop the double quotes:

```
res=$(git status)
```

And then don't `echo` that *without* quotes, or it'll remove all linebreaks:

```
echo "$res"
```

For scripting, consider using

```
git status --porcelain
```

instead (see [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#Documentation/git-status.txt---porcelainltversiongt)), with an easier-to-parse output format that is versioned.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't know this `echo "$res"` about linebreaks.